# Minimal step/value of text-shadow?

Tags: css

What is the minimal step/value of text-shadow? 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 ... ?

```
text-shadow: 0 0 .01px #ddd;
```

Is there a difference in how browsers render this parameter?

Comment: Yes...it's called sub-pixel rounding (or something). Different browsers do it different ways. Some round up...some down. Generally, just use whole pixels you won't be able to see the difference anyway. Plus, of course, there's really no such thing as *half a pixel*.

Comment: @Paulie_D
Thank you! I see. Still the question is what is the min value (like 0.001) that I can yse on, say, 5-7px tiny font when I need a pixel-perfect precision and a shudow like 0.001 or at least 0.01 (this one seems to work fine)...

Comment: There's no such thing as 0.01 of a pixel...what is it you are actually trying to do? If .01px works for you then what's the issue?